# 2 Dimension Linear Regression Math Problem

Tags: matrices, linear-regression

I am trying to self-learning linear regression and I meet a math problem,

Here is the question :

Linear Regression in vector form is 
    
 $y = \beta x + \varepsilon $ 

Where

\begin{equation*}
y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1^T \\ x_2^T \\ \vdots \\ x_n^T
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\beta  = \begin{pmatrix} \beta_0  \\ \beta_1  \\ \vdots \\ \beta_p 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\varepsilon   = \begin{pmatrix} \varepsilon_1  \\ \varepsilon_2  \\ \vdots \\ \varepsilon_n 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Spread :

\begin{align*}
\varepsilon & = y - \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 & \beta_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \end{bmatrix}  \\ \\
& = p^{KO} - \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 & \beta_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ p^{PEP} \end{bmatrix} \\ \\
& = p^{KO} - \beta_0 - \beta_1 p^{PEP}
\end{align*}

This is from one of my course

I know $ \beta $ only have 2 because there is only 2 dimension. 
But why it become  $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \end{bmatrix}$
and Where the '1' come from??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$ is used for the intercept term.

$$\begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 & \beta_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \end{bmatrix} =\beta_0(1)+\beta_1x=\beta_0+\beta_1x$$